# Where to check isFinishing in an activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

I recently realized that to avoid nasty exceptions I should check [isFinishing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) in the inner AsyncTask subclasses of my activity. Where else is it a good practice to check isFinishing in an activity?

Comment: "Not a real question"? Whoever voted to close it care to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You should check to the library DroidFu if you wan't to handle your AsyncTask in case of orientation change and so on.
Anyway, if you read the documentation of isFinishing, it's clearly mentioned where you should use it.

Comment: For starters, the documentation doesn't mention that it should be checked on AsyncTask. I suspect there are many other places where you should check it that the documentation doesn't mention.

Comment: Check this link (http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/introducing-droid-fu-for-android-betteractivity-betterservice-and-betterasynctask/) about BetterAsyncTask